# Подчеркивание заголовка

Tags: html, css

Возможно ли сделать такое подчеркивание как в сниппете, то есть, чтобы бордер был по длине текста, без использования дополнительных тегов внутри заголовка и без `float: left`? Суть в том, что первый вариант не подходит т.к. тексты будут добавляться человеком незнакомым с html\css через редактор, второй, т.к. тогда поедут абзацы находящие после заголовка.
Я знаю 2 способа, первый

```css
h3>span{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<h3><span>Заголовок</span></h3>
```

Второй

```css
h3{
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Заголовок</h3>
```

А вот можно ли как-то без доп тегов и float:left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`display: inline-block;` или какой-то похожий?

```css
h3{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h3>Заголовок</h3>
```

Comment: А во, точно, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

text-decoration
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration

```
h3{
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Думаю ТС хотел подчеркивание, которое можно контролировать по высоте. Хотя могу ошибаться

Comment: @АлексейШиманский всё верно

Answer (score 1):

```css
h3 {      
  display: inline-block;
}

h3:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Заголовок</h3>
```